# Unable to add the file iOS application bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added an empty file with extension `.js` in resource path but that is not added to application's bundle.

I am sure that I have added to application target, but sometimes it includes in bundle and sometimes it doesn't include in bundle.

I am fetching the file's content by following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webscript" ofType:@"js"];
```

Comment: what are you getting if you print filePath?

Comment: Is the file in the Xcode *Copy Resources Build Phase*? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure while adding files to your Xcode project

1. You have checked "Copy items.." checkbox
2. You have selected the "create groups for added folder" radio button
3. "Add to target" check box for your target should be checked

[image]

Comment: From what I can gather the file is in the Xcode project but it's not being copied to the app bundle during a build.

Comment: For this one way is to delete the file from project and again add that with above selected options. And the other way is as your comment @trojanfoe

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add this file to the target:

[image]

Also check if file is in Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

[image]