# Array literals causing huge build times in Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, tuples

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit game in which each level is described by properties of a tuple in an array literal. There are about 150 tuples so far, with each tuple containing about 20 properties.

The problem is, this big array literal causes Xcode to build very slowly. It takes something like 5+ minutes to build my project. If I block out the array, the build time is almost instantaneous.

I think this is due to type inference -- however, I'm explicitly setting the types, like this:

```
class MainData: ObservableObject {
    private var levels: [(firstKey: Int, secondKey: String)] = [
        (
           firstKey: 0,
           secondKey: "something"
        ),
        (
           firstKey: 0,
           secondKey: "something"
        )
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything I can do to this array to speed up my build times?

Thank you!

**Update:** After adding some more tuples, Xcode will actually stop responding and my (brand new, desktop) Mac will run out of application memory.

Comment: You could try moving this into a dedicated module, which will keep the build times of the rest of the app fast (until you touch the game data again): https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times#modularization

Comment: Why don't you make a struct instead of a big tuple?

Comment: @Shadowrun Interesting idea. Why would that build faster, and without crashing Xcode?

Comment: Try it first, but I believe it relates to the type checker. It just seems to be easier for the swift compiler to typecheck e.g. [SomeStruct] than it is to check [(Int, String)], for example, especially as tuples get larger, perhaps there is a big-O issue where the more fields in a tuple, the more ways it could be resolved...

Comment: Any reason why this data needs to be hard-coded? Your sample code looks like it could be a simple JSON bundle that could be loaded when needed by the app instead of compiled.

Comment: @binaryPilot84 Thanks for the suggestion! I need the game to work when the user is *offline*. Wouldn't loading JSON require a connection?

Comment: Only if you are downloading the json from a server...  loading from disk, no connection required

Comment: @Shadowrun Where, exactly, would I would put the JSON? I realize that's probably a dumb question, but I've never done it that way before.

Comment: Put the json file in your app bundle: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-decode-json-from-your-app-bundle-the-easy-way  add files to bundle like e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231153/how-to-add-sound-files-to-your-bundle-in-xcode

Comment: Swift has performance issues, and will have for some time. You might be interested in this tread https://forums.swift.org/t/compile-performance-with-large-constant-arrays-crash-quadratic-behaviour/18143 Please consider filing your scenario in Swift bug tracker.

Comment: Try adding typealiases, ie. "typealias LongListOfTypes = (Int, String, Int, String)"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply extracting each different part of the array literal into its own property, with these new properties being index-coordinated. The game level is the index of these properties.

So, this:

```
    private var levels: [(firstKey: Int, secondKey: String)] = [
        (
           firstKey: 0,
           secondKey: "something"
        ),
        (
           firstKey: 0,
           secondKey: "something"
        )
    ]
```

...becomes this:

```
    private let firstKey: [Int] = [
        0,
        0, //Level 1
        0  //Level 2
    ]
    private let secondKey: [String] = [
        "",
        "something", //Level 1
        "something"  //Level 2
    ]
```

If your original array literal is large, this will be a time-consuming, tedious task -- but it does lower the build times back down to normal.